# JAXBException, Unmarshalling an XML Document

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm getting this exception: Default constructor cannot handle exception type JAXBException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JAXBContext.newInstance` throws a checked exception.  You won't be able to directly set this on a field.  You will need to move it inside your constructor and surround it with a try/catch block.